# Getting error every time Error: Permission denied @ rb_file_s_rename on linkage.json

Tags: macos, permissions, operating-system, homebrew

I have MacOs Catilina 10.15 OS and Homebrew 3.0.11. At every time whenever I am installing package by brew then getting **`Error: Permission denied @ rb_file_s_rename (/Users/username/Library/Caches/Homebrew/.linkage.json20210406-4110-onnsth, /Users/username/Library/Caches/Homebrew/linkage.json)`**

After run this command `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /Users/vineet/Library/Caches/Homebrew` then I can able to install. Here I do not want run `sudo chown..` command for remove `Error: Permission denied @ rb_file_s_rename...`. I want to remove `Permission denied @ rb_file_s_rename` linkage.json error for forever.

Answer (score 3):

I received a warning like "Do you trust these scripts" whenever opening the rails project with Visual Studio Code. Simply I selected "NO". I generated a controller home with a method named index and wanted to navigate the route (http://localhost:3000/home/index). I faced such types of error. I closed my Visual Studio Code and the route (http://localhost:3000/home/index) worked.